# How to code a simple signal logic in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, trading, algorithmic-trading

I want to create a simple trading system signal table with a dataframe such as:

```
            Close   buy   sell
2011-01-31  50       0     0
2011-02-28  40       1     0
2011-03-31  50       0     0
2011-04-30  80       0    -1
2011-05-31  60       1     0
2011-06-30  50       1     0 
2011-07-31  20       0     0
2011-08-31  30       0    -1
```

The signals are generated in a following fashion:

```
df['buy'] = np.where( <condition> , 1, 0 )
```

The **`sell`** column is created in the same way.

The issue is the double buy signal on 2011-06-30, right after a previous one on 2011-05-31.

```
2011-05-31  60       1     0
2011-06-30  50       1     0
```

How can I prevent a new buy ( == 1 ) signal before it is closed with -1 in the **`df['sell']`** column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How can I prevent...?

Well, once in a need of something more complex, than a trivial **`numpy`** vectorised / broadcast / conditional operation alike the stated **`np.where( <condition> , 1, 0 )`** one has to implement some custom-specific function, to handle those additional features, where Finite-State-Automata may well serve for such purposes.

---

### But how to implement it?

Simply said, your conditions have grown beyond the expressivity of simple vectorised/broadcast matrix operations, the Trade-Management sub-system has started to have an internal-, a SEQ-behaviour and some additional rules for it's internal -transition(s) and -transition-restrictions.

One could hardly expect the general, universal tools, the **`numpy`**-matrices and **`pandas`**-DataFrame instances are, to be over-designed to support such problem-domain specific functionalities so as to prototype algo-trading strategy simulations.

Better choose some trading-specific tools to suit such need, or expect to have to implement a SEQ-behaviour iterator-function, that would facilitate the needed logic ( none of the smart numpy vectorised / broadcasting expressions or pandas one-liner will suffice here anymore ).

> **Scope?**
> for those really interested in a rapid prototyped Trading Strategy example, using a FSA-based implementation method, check the simplicity of such system design + built-in ( script-based ) automated conformance-testing capability + line numbers for an estimate of the code-span ( definitely not a `numpy` SLOC ):
>   [image]

Comment: so if I understand you correctly I either have to use an iteration or another programming language?

Comment: Smart mental concepts are typically language agnostic. Python provides sufficient expressivity, just forget to build on one-liners and copy-paste trivial examples from web. If in a real need, python can grow into a node of a heterogeneous distributed processing ( i.e. FORTRAN / MATLAB / and whatever domain-specific processing node(s) can be integrated in such super-system ).

Comment: I would not have expected my described issue requires a complex solution. just from the looks it simply appeared like a simple solution that was just not coming to my mind.

Comment: **Simple? Complex?** BTW, how many years have you been trading on real markets so far? And how many years have you used algo-trading -- at least for quantitative modelling -- of your trading strategies?

Comment: I do not know why this related to my question. But I am not new to validating strategies by excel but new to programming via pandas.

Comment: With all due respect, excel does not help much in quantitative modelling. Given a TruStrategy has at least 5-degrees of freedom, on the highest level of abstraction -- { SelectPOLICY, DetectPOLICY, ActPOLICY, AllocatePOLICY, TerminatePOLICY } -- there are much higher complexities in simulation and the more in highly non-linear optimisation, than a spread-sheet CELL-formula solver or pandas/numpy vectorised/broadcast syntax would ever allow.

Comment: What you say might be true, or not applicable, depending on the task/aim. Still, I would like to see how my initial problem can be solved in pandas.

Comment: You have missed the point. **Neither `pandas`, nor `numpy` allows one to cross-breed the vectorised/broadcast syntax** with any non-stationary-convolution pattern(s) and some state-full SEQ-behaviour with a **mutually conditional behaviour(s) of several `{ buy | sell } <condition>`-s at once.** Asking "I want this and this ... " is possible, however after mastering the `pandas` + `numpy` tools, you will realise the reasons, why these will not have a SLOC-syntax for what you are asking about.

Comment: As stated above **`df['buy'] = np.where( <condition> , 1, 0 )` knows nothing about `df['sell']` and even a clearvoyance would be short to guess it.**

Answer (score 2):

I am bit late for the party but I hope this helps. I suppose you want alternate 1 and -1. Though not the best way, I suggest you add buy and sell signals and call the new column as trade signal. The trade signal column would have 0, 1 and -1 in an arbitrary fashion. The following code explains further steps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
trade_signal= pd.DataFrame([1,1,0,0,-1,-1,1,1,-1])
ts_shifted=trade_signal.shift(1)
trade_rule=np.where(trade_signal!=ts_shifted,trade_signal,0)
```